# Laravel, Scope Methods on Model

Tags: php, laravel

im writing a Laravel Application, that calculates monthly income.

Income table has a column that saves this monthly value. In some months the value will be 0 but when I access to the method using:

$service->income->getMonthTotal(11);

I get the following error (`HasOne could not be converted to string`)

This is the scope method i'm using, where $result is returning 0, and laravel is giving me the error.

Any ideas on how to return 0 for echoing value?

```
public function scopeGetMonthTotal($query, $month)
    {

        $result = $query->where('month',$month)->sum('value');
        return $result;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing relationships as properties will automatically run `get()`, resulting in your error. You need to access your relationship as a method instead:

```
$service->income()->getMonthTotal(11);
```

To see the result, make sure to run `get()` yourself:

```
echo $service->income()->getMonthTotal(11)->get();
```